# Updating UI from worker thread through delegates

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, delegates

For some reason invoking delegates to update to UI doesn't work for one of my threads but using different delegates to update the same controls in a slightly different way does work.

Here's the broken code, I've commented around the lines that are broken to explain

```
Private Sub RunBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RunBtn.Click
    Dim transferThread As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf RunTransfer)
    StartContinuousProg()
    UpdateStatus("Running Transfer...")
    StartTime = Date.Now

    incrementProgMethod = New incrementProgDelegate(AddressOf incrementProg)
    finishProgMethod = New finishProgDelegate(AddressOf finishProg)
    updateStatusMethod = New updateStatusDelegate(AddressOf UpdateStatus)
    writeErrorMethod = New writeErrorDelegate(AddressOf WriteError)
    writeWarningMethod = New writeWarningDelegate(AddressOf WriteWarning)
    writeAlertMethod = New writeAlertDelegate(AddressOf WriteAlert)
    EndTransferMethod = New EndTransferDelegate(AddressOf endTransfer)

    transferThread.Start()

End Sub

Private Sub RunTransfer()

    '(...Some work...)


    For catRow = 0 To CATImportArr.Length - 1
        Dim currentCATSerial, currentCATAsset As String
        currentCATSerial = LCase(CATImportArr(catRow).getSerialNumber)
        currentCATAsset = LCase(CATImportArr(catRow).getAssetNumber)

'This line produces this error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Delegate'.
        Invoke(updateStatusMethod("Searching " & currentCATSerial & ", " & currentCATAsset & "..."))

'This line doesn't crash but the UI label doesn't change
        updateStatusMethod.Invoke("Searching " & currentCATSerial & ", " & currentCATAsset & "...")

'This line doesn't crash but the UI progress bar doesn't change
        Invoke(finishProgMethod)
```

These are the methods being called through the delegates

```
Public Function UpdateStatus(ByRef text As String)
    ParentForm.StatusLbl.Text = text
    Return text
End Function

Public Sub finishProg()
    ParentForm.StatusProg.Value = 100
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Delegate` is simply a class holding a reference to a method. You cannot pass parameters to the `Delegate` itself.

To pass parameters to the method you want to invoke you have to use the [**`Control.Invoke(Delegate, Object())`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1hetckb(v=vs.110).aspx) overload where you pass the parameter(s) to the `Invoke()` method, after you've specified the delegate:

```
Invoke(updateStatusMethod, "Searching " & currentCATSerial & ", " & currentCATAsset & "...")
```

---

Since the second parameter of `Control.Invoke(Delegate, Object())` is declared `ParamArray` you may keep on specifying parameters if you need to by just separating them with a comma:

```
Invoke(updateStatusMethod, [param1], [param2], [param3], ...)
```

Comment: @ImStartingToHateThisSite : If he doesn't want/need `BeginInvoke()` then it's better not to use it. `Begin***` _usually_ requires an `End***` call, and although it has been stated by the WinForms team that it's safe even not doing so (this is specific to controls only) I still wouldn't trust it 100%. Also, _if_ he's using .NET 3.5 or lower he cannot use lambda expressions (`Sub()`).

Comment: Interesting points. I only suggest it because of It's ease of use and cleanliness in the editor. Glad you responded though; I wasn't aware of potential issues with using this. I will need to read on that a little. There are so many features with .net, I'll never be able to read on them all...

Comment: @ImStartingToHateThisSite : Yes there are a lot of features indeed. When calling `Begin***` you _usually_ must follow by calling `End***` sometime afterwards, otherwise you will get memory and thread leaks. BUT it has apparently been stated by the WinForms team that `Control.BeginInvoke()` should be safe to use without calling `EndInvoke()` ([it is even stated on the MSDN that `EndInvoke()` is not necessary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3(v=vs.110).aspx): _"You can call EndInvoke to retrieve the return value from the delegate, if neccesary, but this is not required"_)

Comment: @ImStartingToHateThisSite : In conclusion `EndInvoke()` is used to receive the return value of the asynchronous operation and to dispose of any resources, threads, etc. used by it, which is why it is _usually_ an important call. I can't tell what would make `Control.BeginInvoke()` safe to use without `EndInvoke()`... Well, what does one know? Programming is complicated. :)